# question about "In" vs "For"

Tags: prepositions, difference

> The agency expects the U.S. will continue to produce more oil than Russia and Saudi Arabia **for** the rest of this year.

My question is, can I use "in the rest of this year", it is correct? What are the differences of "in the rest of this year" and "for the rest of this year"?

Comment: Why do you want to use "in"? Any justification in dictionary definitions? Or you saw such usage elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation there is no point in using "in" at all.

The difference between "In the rest of the year" and "For the rest of the year" is pretty much

"In the rest of the year" = "During the rest of the year"

and

"For the rest of the year" = "For the entire duration of the rest of the year"

so story in short, For is when you do something for the set "duration" for example here it's for the rest of the year, and "in" will be used when it's "sometime" during the rest of the year.